# VBA function is not saved

Tags: excel, vba

I have written my own function for computation have to do very often. 
The problem is that when I write it to the xlam file were all my functions are stored
this particular function is not saved. After closing EXCEL and opening it again it is disappeared.
I have nailed the problem down to the decision that is wrong with code. But so far I could not figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here is my code.

```
Function isotpologues(R_13 As Variant, R_17 As Variant, R_18 As Variant, u_r13 As Variant, u_r17 As Variant, u_r18 As Variant) As Variant()

Dim results As Variant
ReDim results(1 To 11, 1 To 3)

results(1, 1) = "R_12_16_17"
results(2, 1) = "R_12_16_18"
results(3, 1) = "R_12_17_17"
results(4, 1) = "R_12_17_18"
results(5, 1) = "R_12_18_18"

results(6, 1) = "R_13_16_16"
results(7, 1) = "R_13_16_17"
results(8, 1) = "R_13_16_18"
results(9, 1) = "R_13_17_17"
results(10, 1) = "R_13_17_18"
results(11, 1) = "R_13_18_18"

results(1, 2) = 2 * R_17

results(2, 2) = 2 * R_18

results(3, 2) = R_17 ^ 2

results(4, 2) = R_17 * R_18 * 2

results(5, 2) = R_18 * R_18


results(6, 2) = R_13

results(7, 2) = R_13 * R_17 * 2

results(8, 2) = R_13 * R_18 * 2

results(9, 2) = R_13 * R_17 ^ 2

results(10, 2) = R_13 * R_17 * R_18 * 2

results(11, 2) = R_13 * R_18 * R_18


results(1, 3) = 2 * (u_r17) * 2

results(2, 3) = 2 * (u_r18) * 2

results(3, 3) = 2 * (R_17) * (u_r17) * 2

results(4, 3) = (4 * R_17 ^ 2 * u_r18 ^ 2 + 4 * R_18 ^ 2 * u_r17 ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 2

results(5, 3) = 2 * (R_18) * (u_r18) * 2

results(6, 3) = (u_r13) * 2

results(7, 3) = (4 * R_13 ^ 2 * u_r17 ^ 2 + 4 * R_17 ^ 2 * u_r13 ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 2

results(8, 3) = (4 * R_13 ^ 2 * u_r18 ^ 2 + 4 * R_18 ^ 2 * u_r13 ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 2

results(9, 3) = (4 * R_13 ^ 2 * R_17 ^ 2 * u_r17 ^ 2 + R_17 ^ 4 * u_r13 ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 2

results(10, 3) = (4 * R_13 ^ 2 * R_17 ^ 2 * u_r18 ^ 2 + 4 * R_13 ^ 2 * R_18 ^ 2 * u_r17 ^ 2 + 4 * R_17 ^ 2 * R_18 ^ 2 * u_r13 ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 2

results(11, 3) = (4 * R_13 ^ 2 * R_18 ^ 2 * u_r18 ^ 2 + R_18 ^ 4 * u_r13 ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 2

isotpologues = results

End Function
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't have anything to do with how its gets saved in a .xlam. My guess is that you have an excel file (.xlsm or .xlsb) open with the .xlam open in the background and you are only saving the foreground excel file. To ensure you a saving the .xlam, you should open the vb-editor, make sure you have the .xlam project selected, and save from the VBE.

Comment: Have you tried to save my function?, I tried the way you suggested,but this was not the solution.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question. I'm gathering that you are trying to save code in a .xlam (add-in file). You write the above function in a module in the .xlam vbaproject. Then, you click "Save" to save the .xlam. You get no indication that the .xlam has failed to save; you check the .xlam file for its "Last Modified" property in a File Explorer and all looks good. But then, you close and reopen the very same .xlam file and see that your code is not there?

Comment: okay, update cannot save any function, anymore :(

Comment: There is no error message, but I checked the last modified date and this does not change, it is still yesterday, but I have tried it today several times. Yes the situation is as you describe it!

Comment: Can you try opening only that .xlam file, making sure no other excel file is open, and changing/saving that way? You'll need to try and isolate this file. If it won't save, perhaps your file is busted ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Okay, I tried that but still the same 